# Trying to create separates cards

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a series of cards ordered by years, the main idea would be that inside the main div, there is a div that creates each card as it goes through the for, the problem is that when it ends, it puts everything in a list inside single div and not as a separate card per year, can any of you help me?

Thank you!

```
<head>
  <style>
  #card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 13%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0.5%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="card"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    let d = new Date();
    let n = d.getFullYear();
    for(n; n >= 1990; n--){
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      let card = document.createElement("div");

      card.innerHTML = n;
      div.appendChild(card);

      document.getElementById("card").appendChild(card);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want a nested element like this: `<div><div>1990</div></div>`?

Comment: Yes, this should be something like <div>1995</div><div>1994</div><div>1993</div><div>1992</div> etc.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Thanks bro! No, probably I explained myself in a wrong way, the idea is that each year are in separate cards, not just in one. I'm new in programming.

Comment: No problem, that was my bad, check the updated answer, hope it works for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you want each one of your element to be like this: `<div id='card'>1990</div>`, so **since `id` should be unique in DOM element we can’t create multiple instances like the above one so we should either generate our elements with class or dynamic id**.
Here is the final result:

```html
<body>
  <div id="main"></div>
  <script>
    let d = new Date();
    let n = d.getFullYear();
    for (n; n >= 1990; n--) {
      const card = document.createElement("div");
      card.className = 'card';
      // card.setAttribute('id', `card-${n}`); // Or you can give it a dynamic id like this
      card.innerHTML = n  
      document.getElementById("main").appendChild(card);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @SMAKSS! So, in case I require multiple instances, I have to use class not id, I didn't know that